# Maven exec won't recognize my app in src/test

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, server, classloader

I am trying to run a mvn exec for one of my spring boot apps but it is giving me a class loader exception.

I have an app in main named App.java that runs of 28433 port. 
I also have an app in src/test named MockServerApp.java.

I am trying to run mvn exec to execute them. 
When I do mvn exec on my main app it works and starts. When I do it on my MockServerApp though it causes a class loader exception.

Here is my POM

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>second-cli</id>
            <configuration>                           
<mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Here is the error I am getting :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:835)
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT: I have tried using the spring-boot-maven-plugin since I will be using the MockAppServer for integration tests and have tried launching both in the pre-integration life cycle.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.App</mainClass>   

        </configuration>  
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>

                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test2</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
               <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp</mainClass>   
                    </configuration> 

                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>

                         <goal>stop</goal>                  
                    </goals>
                     <configuration>
               <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.App</mainClass>   
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test2</id>
                    <goals>

                         <goal>stop</goal>                  
                    </goals>
                     <configuration>
               <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp</mainClass>   
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Still gives me the classNotFoundException.

Comment: The problem is not in what you've shown.  You identified the main class but that class is not included in the generated/deployed jar.

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry, I'm new to Maven/spring, can you expand on that?

Comment: The error is somewhere else.  It's trying to run the class you specified, but that class is not available.  With what you've posted we cannot begin to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @JimGarrison should I post my project structure? It is in my class path in eclipse IDE  but under src/test/java

Comment: The exact difference between `src/test` and `src/main` is that `src/test` is not available during packaging or running, only during the test phase. You'll need to either split this into multiple modules or use Spring Boot's configuration capabilities to change the behavior at runtime based on properties or similar.

Comment: @chrylis I edited with further things I have tried in regards to your comment. I have tried running my integration test to hit with my mockserver and have my main app running pre-integration but it does not connect(post request) and gives a httphostconnectexception.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark MockServerApp with following annotations. And instead of trying to run MockServerApp from maven, you can simply run junits from maven and let Spring manage creation of test context.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

You can see further documentation at [spring boot testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)